# connect 4 diagonal win checker only works one way

Tags: python, numpy

For a terminal based game of connect 4, I got the game to successfully check for horizontal, vertical wins but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong when checking for a diagonal win going left, especially since diagonal win going right works fine.

the board is a 2d array with numpy in python, 6x7 is standard connect 4 size and the 'player' is just a string of 'X' or 'O' representing the player

```
def checkDiagonal(brd, player):
for i in range(len(brd[0]) - 4):# Checks 4 spots diagonally going right
    for j in range(len(brd) - 2): 
        if brd[i][j] == player and brd[i + 1][j + 1] == player and brd[i + 2][j + 2] == player and brd[i + 3][j + 3] == player:
            return True

for i in range(len(brd[0]) - 2, 3, -1): # checks for 4 spots diagonally going left
    for j in range(len(brd) - 2, 0, -1): 
        if brd[i][j] == player and brd[i - 1][j - 1] == player and brd[i - 2][j - 2] == player and brd[i - 3][j - 3] == player:
            return True

return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how you coded it: you check the same direction, but from both ends.  You didn't check your logic with pencil and paper.  To go in the other diagonal, the indices must increment in opposite directions: one up, one down.  For instance:

```
    if brd[i][j] == player and brd[i - 1][j + 1] == player and brd[i - 2][j + 2] == player and brd[i - 3][j + 3] == player:
```

I leave the bounds checking and loop ranges as an exercise for the coder.  :-)